# Sencha touch getting text into textarea

Tags: text, sencha-touch

I am using sencha touch to query a web server which returns text data.

my current code is the following:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'get/log',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (result, request) {

                alert("Success");
                Ext.getCmp('logText').setValue(request)

    },
    failure: function (result, request) {

        alert("FAILED");
        Ext.getCmp('logText').setValue(request)
    }
});
```

This is not working as expected as I'm seeing `[object Object]` in the text area.

The server is sending the following (as a example).

```
[17 Oct 10:41:53] Beacon off
[17 Oct 10:41:53] Beacon on
```

Does anybody have any advice / experience on how best to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the server response in `result.responseText`. Anyway you should set a breakpoint in the success function and inspect what and where the server is returning.